# ¿Llenar datos de una colección en mongoose con datos de otra colección a través de un POST en Express?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

Tengo dos colecciones destinadas para una API, una colección llamada `animatronics` y otra llamada `types`.

Lo que necesito, es que en la colección de `animatronics` al momento de llenar sus datos a través de un POST con express, pueda indicarle al ID del tipo de animatronico que es y así, no tener que escribirlo manualmente.

La colección de animatronicos se ve así (por ahora):

```
const mongo = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const animatronicSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    type: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Types'
        }
    },
    techInf: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
            genre: "Unknown",
            mainColor: "MainColor",
            eyeColor: "EyeColor",
            accs: ""
        }
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                name: "Unknown",
                url: ""
            }
        }
    },
    affiliations: {
        type: Object,
        default: {
            location: "Unknown",
            url: ""
        }
    },
    appearances: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongo.model('Animatronics', animatronicSchema);
```

Mientras que la colección de types se ve así:

```
const mongo = require('mongoose');

const typesSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    members: {
        type: Array,
        items: {
            type: Object,
            default: {
                name: "Unknown",
                url: ""
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongo.model('Types', typesSchema);
```

Mi controlador se ve así:

```
const Animatronic = require('../models/animatronicModel');

const animatronicCtrl = {
    getList: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const animatronics = await Animatronic.find();
            if (animatronics.length < 1) return res.status(404).json({msg: 'Not Found'});

            res.json({animatronics});
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    },
    uploadAnim: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { name, type, techInf, createdBy, affiliations, appearances } = req.body;
            if (!name) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Name required'});
            const animExist = await Animatronic.findOne({ name });
            if (animExist) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Animatronic already exists'});

            if (appearances.length < 1) return res.status(400).json({msg: 'Appearances required'});

            const newAnim = new Animatronic({
                name,
                type,
                techInf,
                createdBy,
                affiliations,
                appearances
            });

            await newAnim.save();
            return res.json({msg: 'Animatronic uploaded'});
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
    }
};

module.exports = animatronicCtrl;
```

Y la petición en postman sería tal que así:

```
{
    "name": "Random",
    "appearances": ["Five Nights at Freddy's 2", "Ultimate Custom Night"]
}
```

Destacar que solo pongo los datos de "name" y "appearances" porque los demás no son obligatorios y tienen un default y solo estoy testeando, también no he colocado el "type" porque no sé de que manera enviarlo.

Gracias!!

Comment: Lo puedes pasar de mchas formas, por ejemplo podrias mandar el nombre (si es unico para esa colección)… si es asi, lo buscás en la base de datos por el nombre y si lo encuentras le sacas el id y ese es el que insertas en el animatronic